# Regression Modelling with Sets of Vectors

Tags: regression, machine-learning, neural-networks, boosting

Hi I've a regression Machine Learning problem of the following form:

Input: $\{(o_i,v_i)| o_i \in R^d, v_i \in R , i \in \{1,2,3,...M\} \}$
Output: $s \in R$

I can use a neural model (probably  *deep sets* ) however $o_i \in R^d$ is a feature vector that is a concatenation of multiple categorical and continuous variables. Are there research papers dealing with similar input? What other model options do I have?

N.T. I have kept $o_i$ and $v_i$ separate as in the training dataset $o_i$ appears with a broad range of $v_i$. Think of it as multiple amount ($v_i$) of ingredients ($o_i$) are getting added in different recipes and we are measuring measuring the 'hotness' of the food.

Thank you in advance.